# ASP.NET MVC Contrib Projects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am looking to get on with contributors on an ASP.NET MVC Project.  I am professionally developing for a large firm and don't get enough of it here.  I also teach Java Object Oriented practices at a University, and still don't feel that I get enough of the engineering with this.  Simply put, I am looking to get onto a project (small, opensource) so that I can gain valuable information and learn from others in the community before I go crazy here (I have reached a proverbial ceiling where I am).

Where is the best place to look for this type of work?

My wannabe expertises... JQuery, ASP.NET MVC, CSharp, AJAX, Javascript, Memberships, and the list continues on.  Previous work is mostly private (intranet), so all I have is a couple sites I have put together.  http://jancel.doesntexist.com (is one that I am currently working on, won't be here forever, just waiting for customer buyoff).  http://hurl.me is the first MVC C# Project I took on to learn more on ASP.NET MVC C#.  My experiences started at Preview 2 and am excited to get on board here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are any number of open source projects that could easily use a major refactoring of their codebase (and know it). I'd start with SourceForge, find a few you're interested in for their subject matter, and start a conversation. (From your point of view, they don't even need to be currently ASP sites.)

Answer (score 1):

How about [MvcContrib](http://www.codeplex.com/MVCContrib)?  Another thought is [Code Camp Server](http://code.google.com/p/codecampserver/), but I'm not sure how active it is in terms of new features.